# Check the uri is valid

Tags: c#

```
Uri myuri = new Uri("https://buffalousercontent.blob.core.windows.net/371-static/profileimages/full/39398");
```

This is my uri, when u hit means it receives image based on user some user doesn't contains image at that time it receives error page.

How to check the received one is image or something in C# code?

Comment: Uri myuri = new Uri("https://buffalousercontent.blob.core.windows.net/371-static/profileimages/full/39354598"); Example:  invalid one

Comment: Is there any class to check this...

Comment: Valid as in well formed or valid as in it returns what you are expecting?

Comment: It returns some error page.. Hit the above url and commented url to find the difference... How to find these things in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answers, you can look at the content type of the response, or you could try to create an image from the URI.

```
try {
    var client = new WebClient();
    var image = Image.FromStream(client.OpenRead(uri));
}
catch(ArguementException e) {
    // this exception will be thrown if the URI doesn't point to a valid image.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking to validate that the URL contains an image:

```
bool ValidateImage(string url)
{
    HttpWebRequest r = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    r.Method = "GET";

    try
    {
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)r.GetResponse();

        if (resp.ContentType == "image/jpeg")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Image retrieved successfully.");
            // Process image
            return true;
        }
        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to retrieve image");
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Unable to retrieve image.");
    }

    return false;
}
```

Obviously, change the `ContentType` check to whatever makes sense for your application. You could also use `HEAD` as the request method (as in [@Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25162283/497356)' answer) if you're *just* looking to validate the content type and not download the entire image right then.

Comment: `GetResponse` is a method on `HttpWebResponse` which is in the System.Net namespace.

Answer (score 0):

To check if there is an error, you have to send a request and then receive an error or a good blob.

To send a request, you can use `WebClient` as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :

```
public bool CheckUri(Uri uri){
   using(var client = new WebClient()){

   try{
        client.DownloadFile(uri);
        return true;
    }catch{//error detected
     return false;
   }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a httprequest and check if the response contenttype equals "image/". This function should do the trick!

```
Boolean IsImageUrl(string URL)
{
    var req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);
    req.Method = "HEAD";
    using (var resp = req.GetResponse())
    {
        return resp.ContentType.ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                   .StartsWith("image/");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well a `Uri` object itself doesn't know what will happen when you use it as the address of a GET request.

To check if a `string` is a valid `Uri`, you can use

```
Uri uri;
bool valid = Uri.TryCreate(stringInput, UriKind.Absolute, out uri);
```

To check what the file type of a request is

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = client.GetAsync(uri).Result;

    var contentType = response.Content.Headers.ContentType;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Azure client API to do this. Add a reference to `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient`:

```
    bool IsBlobJpeg(string blobUri)
    {
        try
        {
            Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudBlob blob =
                new CloudBlob(
                    blobUri);
            blob.FetchAttributes();
            return (blob.Properties.ContentType == "image/jpeg");

        }
        catch (StorageClientException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} Does not exist", blobUri));
            return false;
        }
    }
```